# What's the origin of the word "chido"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, méxico

1. What's the origin of the word "chido"?
2. When did it become popular in Mexico?

**Examples:**

> Qué chido esta tu carro.
>
> Estaría bien chido si ganara la lotería.

**RAE**:

> chido, da.
>
> 1. adj. Méx. bonito (? lindo).
> 2. adj. coloq. Méx. Muy bueno.

Comment: ***Diccionario breve de mexicanismos***, [which is online at the Academia mexicana de la lengua](http://www.academia.org.mx/dicmex.php) is a great place to look for such terms, but on this occasion they have no etymology to offer but they do have some variants I was not aware of: `**chido**, **chida**, o **chiro**, **chira**, o **shido**, **shida**. adj. 1. Bueno, de lo mejor. || 2. Bonito.`

Comment: Curious, my dictionary doesn't even have a definition for this word (Babylon). Good question! +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several theories as to the origin of **Chido** the one that is the most accepted one is that it came on the migratory waves of the XIX century coming from *Asturias* in Spain. From the word *xidu* in asturian, that practically means beautiful, and nice.

The term first appeared officially in Mexico under the dictionary of criminal slang of Carlos Roumagnac in 1904.

> Según la conjetura que goza de mejores fundamentos (tanto lingüísticos como históricos), la palabra chido tendría su origen en el asturiano xidu (pronunciado ʃidu),[1](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chido) de donde habría pasado al xido del léxico mexicano a través de las oleadas migratorias del siglo XIX, y finalmente al vernáculo chido por mediación de los movimientos culturales de los años sesenta y setenta del siglo XX. Efectivamente, en lengua bable la palabra xidu significa "hermoso", "bello", "bonito", "bueno",[2] y, de hecho, el término (con precisamente las mismas acepciones) aparece en México documentado por primera vez en 1904 bajo la voz xido del diccionario de jerga criminal de Carlos Roumagnac.[3] La forma xido (en vez de xidu) tendría su justificación lingüística en que las formas equivalentes a los vocablos asturianos terminados en -u suelen presentar la terminación -o en castellano, teniendo casi siempre su origen ambas desinencias en las latinas -us y -um, pero a veces formándose por analogía o simple asimilación.[4] En cuanto al valor fonético ʃ, representado por la x, éste con frecuencia pasa al castellano como ch, lo cual explicaría la ulterior transformación de xido en chido.[5] Por último, la verosimilitud histórico-social de este presunto préstamo se ve reforzada por la importante migración de asturianos a México durante los siglos XIX y XX.

Another theory states that **chido** derives from the word in spanish **chiro** that in the streets means brilliant. Specially in Tepito, Mexico.

So to answer the question it most likely became popular during the XX century, used mainly in slang. And its origin is debatable, though the most accepted theory is it comes from asturian **xidu**.

There are additional theories that are documented on wikipedia if you further read the references sources.

[Source](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chido)

Comment: We would then need to ask where **chiro** comes from, and whether it also goes back to the Asturian word.